# unwanted characters on Zencart portuguese language header

Tags: php, zen-cart

i have installed Portuguese language pack in my zencart website.

its showing English pages fine but when click on Portuguese page it change css a bit and also header has margin. I have spent few hours to fix it but can't what exactly happening.

here is the link http://mydaydresses.com/index.php?main_page=index&language=Pr

Comment: Yeah, that link goes to a godaddy holding page. Try again?

Comment: i had to change the hosting for while i will make website online very soon. then please see and and update me the issue